# NVidia presentation about new OpenGL seems to claim GLSL has now #include directives

Tags: opengl, glsl, opengl-4

According to [those slides](https://developer.nvidia.com/sites/default/files/akamai/gamedev/docs/OpenGL%204.x%20and%20Beyond.pdf) by nvidia (slide 24), there seems to be some kind of include directives in recent  opengl / glsl.

According to [the wiki](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Core_Language_(GLSL)#Preprocessor_directives), this does not seem true : "[...]. The most notable omission is #include."

So, who is right here ? If I should do this by myself or not is not the question, I just want precisions about what NVidia seemed to claim during this presentation.

Comment: OpenGL itself is already old, i would not count on this features. Vulkan is much clearer here.

Comment: @FelixK.: ... huh? I'm not sure how that addresses what the OP said. Further, OpenGL is plenty clear on this matter. It's not OpenGL's fault that NVIDIA is misrepresenting things.

Comment: @FelixK.: If you want to evangelize Vulkan, this is not the right place to do it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a misrepresentation from NVIDIA about what's going on. For some reason, NVIDIA has decided to present extension-only functionality right alongside core functionality, *without* any statements about what parts are extension-only.

What this slide is referring to is [ARB_shading_language_include](https://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/ARB/shading_language_include.txt), an OpenGL extension that *has not* be incorporated into any version of OpenGL. Indeed, if [this database is accurate](http://opengl.gpuinfo.org/gl_listreports.php?listreportsbyextension=GL_ARB_shading_language_include), then the *only implementations* of OpenGL that expose this extension are written by NVIDIA.

So if you use this feature, you're tying yourself to NVIDIA's hardware.

Comment: I'm not sure how this is a misrepresentation -- *everything* in the presentation slide deck is an extension and not in core.  They're very up-front about it.

Comment: @ChrisDodd: Here's a partial list of things that were core OpenGL functionality at the time those slides were made: texture storage, debug output, separate shader objects, explicit attribute/uniform/sampler/UBO/SSBO bindings, compute shaders, sampler objects, etc, and that was *just the first half* of the slides. Oh yes, there are companion extensions that expose those features too. But they exist in core OpenGL versions, not *just* as an extension. Unlike, for example, ARB_shading_language_include. So yes, it's a misrepresentation.